# Glassfish 4 REST XML Working JSON Error

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb, glassfish

I have a web service on Glassfish 4.1 that is working properly for XML but not for JSON.

The entity class is:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8969081094076790550L;
    Integer id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String employeeId;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Person() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + " [" + employeeId + "] [id: " + id + "]";
    }
    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }
    /**
     * @param firstName the firstName to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the lastName
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }
    /**
     * @param lastName the lastName to set
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the employeeId
     */
    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return this.employeeId;
    }
    /**
     * @param employeeId the employeeId to set
     */
    public void setEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

The relevant service code is:

```
@GET
@Path("xml")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public Collection<Person> getPeopleXML() {
    return personDao.getAllPeople(); 
}

@GET
@Path("json")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Collection<Person> getPeopleJSON() {
    return personDao.getAllPeople(); 
}
```

The XML call works, and I get:

```
<people>
 <person>
  <employeeId>2234</employeeId>
  <firstName>Mike</firstName>
  <id>2</id>
  <lastName>Jones</lastName>
 </person>
 <person>
  <employeeId>22314</employeeId>
  <firstName>Joe</firstName>
  <id>4</id>
  <lastName>Smith</lastName>
 </person>
</people>
```

I get an error with the JSON call:

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector root
>   cause
>
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector root
>   cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector root
>   cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector not found
>   by com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider [129] note
>   The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
>   available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.

Why the error?  I have everything I need, I think.  I have an ivy file and tried adding all kinds of jackson deps, but nothing seems to work.  I cannot tell if I am having version problems when I add jackson to my ivy file since it's included with Glassfish, or what.

Glassfish provides the following:

```
/d/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/jackson-annotations.jar
/d/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/jackson-core.jar
/d/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/jackson-databind.jar
/d/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/jackson-jaxrs-base.jar
/d/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider.jar
/d/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/jersey-media-json-jackson.jar
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the solution:

1. Stop Glassfish
2. Delete all of the jackson stuff in the modules directory for Glassfish.
3. Delete the domains/domain1/osgi-cache/felix directory
4. Copy the following files to that directory:

> /glassfish/modules/jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar
>
> /glassfish/modules/jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar
>
> /glassfish/modules/jackson-core-2.4.2.jar
>
> /glassfish/modules/jackson-core-2.5.4.jar
>
> /glassfish/modules/jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar
>
> /glassfish/modules/jackson-databind-2.5.4.jar
>
> /glassfish/modules/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.5.4.jar
>
> /glassfish/modules/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.5.4.jar
>
> /glassfish/modules/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.4.2.jar
>
> /glassfish/modules/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.5.4.jar
>
> /glassfish/modules/jersey-media-json-jackson.jar

Then it works.  Not sure what version the original files for Jackson were, but this works and upgrades your jackson module versions.

Comment: Wow, this is really a big bug in Glassfish. In WildFly it worked out of the box. Thanks for answering it yourself!

Comment: Yeah, I've since given up on Glassfish and moved to WildFly.  Glassfish had too many bugs like this that just wasted way too much of my time.

Comment: You just helped me out big time!

Comment: Good, I'm pretty sure you don't need both versions of the jackson stuff, but I have since given up on Glassfish so I can't test.

Comment: Thanks sir, you saved my day. One thing: In my case, I did all the things you point in that list except for /glassfish/modules/jersey-media-json-jackson.jar.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem in which i battled with it for days.
The problem is a missing jar file ( jackson-module-jaxb-annotations ) in glashfish 4.1.1. You can download it from this link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonmodulejaxbannotations212jar.htm or google download jackson module jaxb annotations.
Then include it in C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\modules directory. you can rename the jar file by removing the version number. Restart glassfish and redeploy your app. It works for me that way

Answer (score 0):

The same problem here, in my case just included the maven repository for "**Jackson Module: JAXB Annotations**" in my pom.xml redeploy and ready. I had to make the http call twice I don't really know why but this worked for me in the second call (GET/POST http request).

Hope this helps someone else.